# How to set the minimum number of nodes visited by each vehicle or set the minimum traveling time for each vehicle?

Tags: python, or-tools

I am working on a vehicle routing problem.

I have formulated it as a CVRP problem and the objective is to minimize the total time (no time window constraints, I just used the CVRP example code from https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/cvrp and replaced the distance matrix with the travel time matrix between each node).

The problem I am facing is: In the solution there is a significant difference between the total time each vehicle travels. (eg. vehicle 1 travels 300 mins but vehicle 2 travels 150 mins).

Is there any way to decrease such difference? I am thinking of adding a constraint to the model and I have tried adding dimension for each vehicle by using `routing.AddDimension()` However, I think `AddDimension()` only allows me to set the maximum. How should I approach this problem?? 
Like is there a way for me to set the minimum number of nodes visited by each vehicle or the minimum traveling time for each vehicle?
Thanks!

I am thinking of adding a constraint to the model and I have tried adding dimension for each vehicle by using `routing.AddDimension()` However, I think `AddDimension()` only allows me to set the maximum.

Comment: If you're minimizing the length of the longest single travel, then the only way to bring them closer is to increase the travel time of the first vehicle; do you want that?